# nested loops in java

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm trying to make a diagonal line that should look like this:

```
*
 *
  *
   *
    *
     *
      *
       *
        *
```

I have to use nested loops and I am using a program called Java ready to program which uses java. 
Here is my code which is close but I can't seem to figure out how to make it diagonal.

```
// The "E006" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class E006
{
    static Console c;           // The output console

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        c = new Console ();
        int i, j;
        for(i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
            for(j = 1; j < 10; j++)
                c.println("*");

    } // main method
} // E006 class
```

I'm sure it is something very simple, but I am just starting out so I'm not too sure what to do. I must use nested loops (a loop inside a loop).

It would be a great help if someone could help me with this.

Comment: your code isn't javascript. its java.

Comment: Do you think you would learn anything if we solved your exercises for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a school assignment, so I'm not going to solve it for you.  Here are some hints:

- You need to print spaces, not just asterisks
- You need to print more spaces on each line
- Your first for loop only executes once, what good is a loop that happens once
- Your code would be easier to read with better indentation.   Use brackets around your for loops even when they aren't required.

---

```
int i, j;
for(i = 1; i <= 1; i++){
    for(j = 1; j < 10; j++){
        c.println("*");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first loop should go over the number of * line items you want to print. The second inner loop should print the white spaces before printing the asterisk. I don't really see the use for nested loops. But if you must use them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lineSegments; i++) { 
   int whitespaces = 0;
   for (int j = 0; j < whiteSpaces; j++)
       Console.print(" ");
   Console.print("*\n");
   whitespaces++;
   Console.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Hehh{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int i, j;
        for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(j = 0; j <= i; j++){
                if(j == i) System.out.println("*");
                else System.out.print(" ");
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always avoid checking for a specific iteration in a loop. It slows the whole loop down and makes it harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use proper loop structure. you have the comparison parts fine, just moved the iterators down to start at 0 because it's more natural for this problem.

You should build the string as you go along as well.

```
// The "E006" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class E006
{
    static Console c;           // The output console

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    c = new Console ();
    final int NUM_ROWS = 10 // set this for number of rows
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
        String thisLine = "";
        for(j = ; j < i; j++) {
            thisLine += " ";
        } // inner loop
        thisLine += "*";
        c.println(thisLine);
    } // outer loop

    } // main method
} // E006 class
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you intended (untested):

```
// The "E006" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class E006
{
    static Console c;           // The output console

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        c = new Console();
        int i, j;
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                c.print(" ");
            }
            c.println("*");
        }
    } // main method
} // E006 class
```

Why does it (should it) work? In the first loop (i=0) it loops 0 times printing spaces, then adds an asterisk with a newline (println adds a newline after the end). Next loop, it prints one space before the asterisk, next prints 2, etc.

p.s. is this homework? you should tag it.

Comment: hey, thanks this helped me so much. I can finally continue with this java.

Comment: Glad it helped. And to whoever down-voted: why? There's nothing wrong with this answer (unless maybe Console doesn't behave as used in the question, but that's unrelated)